# Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed worklight 6.1.0.1 on eclipse kepler from marketplace. I am getting the following error when I tried to build the application.

" Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify that the Worklight server is started and reachable.Connection to - 192.168.112.1:10080 failed. (Permission denied: connect)."

We send SOAP requests from the adapter. The backend services are only accessible if connected to VPN. I have connected to VPN and deployed the application. few JS files like dojo.js are pointing to local IP. For building the project to VPN IP , I right clicked the project and Run As>Build Settings and deploy targets. In the window that is popped up, I gave the VPN IP and cliked Ok. Again I right clicked project Run As>build all and deploy all. But still its being pointing to local IP 192.168.112.1:10080 and getting the error mentioned above when I try to deploy the application.

Even if I open project on worklight project console, its redirecting to local IP.

Comment: Deployment is done to your LOCAL server, use localhost in Servers view > Worklight Development Server.

Comment: Can you explain me in details as to how to go and change in Worklight 6.1.0.1. Thank you :)

Comment: Open the server view in Eclipse. Double-click on "Worklight Development Server". Verify the address says "localhost". If it is already "localhost", the problem is different.

Comment: Yes it is already set to localhost only

Comment: Why do you need at all VPN here? it's not related if you are developing locally on your developer machine.

Comment: I can access the services only if I connect to VPN

Comment: What services? deployment takes place on your LOCAL machine, there is no need for remote connection. I don't understand your scenario. Click on the Edit above in the question and explain.

Comment: @IdanAdar: Hi, Its edited. Please let me know if you still dont get it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think some ideas are mixed here.

Your application will be running in a local Worklight test server, that as part of Worklight Studio is placed in your development environment (localhost). If your adapters must use the VPN to reach the backend services, then you must only make sure the your-adapter.xml referes to the correct HTTP host (i.e. an IP address available through the VPN).

You should not need to change your local server address, i.e. if you double-click the Worklight Development Server in Servers view, the Host name field should be "localhost" (without quotes, that's the default value), or preferrable a local IP, may be 192.168.112.1 (or whatever local IP you have). If after trying all this, that still don't work, I'd change that to your VPN IP, but I believe that's not necessary.

One thing you may not be aware of is that when doing a build and deploy to Worklight Development Server, and you have the host name set to "localhost" the Worklight Studio will "guess" your IP, so that's probably the problem you are facing.

In a nutshell, what I'd do is:
 1. Make sure your server host name is still localhost (or a fixed local IP address)
 2. Make sure your adapter.xml file(s) refer to a correct IP or fully qualified host name in the VPN, so you can reach them.
 3. Run As -> Build All and Deploy
 4. Test

What I'm saying here is if you want your app built using the VPN IP, then you don't need to do it through Build Settings and Deploy Target, but just going to Servers View, double-click on Worklight Development Server and then set the Host name to the IP you want. The Build All and Deploy will do the rest for you.